# Vertical Fixed Box at bottom of screen using MUI

Tags: css, material-ui

So far I have tried this:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { Box, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import styled from "@emotion/styled";
export default function App() {
  const MainStyle = styled("div")(({ theme }) => ({
    position: "fixed",
    zIndex: 99999,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0
  }));
  return (
    <MainStyle>
      <Box sx={{ transform: "rotate(-90deg)", backgroundColor: "blue" }}>
        <Typography sx={{ color: "white" }}>CHAT WITH US!</Typography>
      </Box>
    </MainStyle>
  );
}
```

The problem with this is that half the box is out of the screen and is not all the way to the right.[image: Problem]

My goal is to have it all the way in the right corner but also show the entire box like up against the side like https://proxy-seller.com/ have their "chat with us, we are online" just I want it on the right side.

Comment: check if there is a padding that impact the position, you can also use position fixed to put it where ever u want

Comment: ```writing-mode: vertical-rl;``` you can the mentioned css property.

Comment: Cool, I have just added it as answer for future post reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`writing-mode: vertical-rl;` you can the mentioned css property.

- Simple `html` example for `writing-mode: vertical-rl`, you can lear more about it from [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode).

  ```css
  .main {
    position: relative;
  }

  .text {
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 15px;
    height: 120px;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <main class="main">
    <h1 class="text">Test text</h1>
  </main>
  ```